# Set visibility (visible, invisible) of DrawingVisual on a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Is there a way to set visibility of DrawingVisual object other than removing it from the canvas (for invisibility) and redraw it using information stored somewhere to make it visible again?

I want to do it after DrawingContext of the DrawingVisual has been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DrawingVisual` doesn't have `Visibility` property, as it doesn't derive from `FrameworkElement`.

So you cannot do that that easily. However, you can make it transparent, by adjusting `VisualOpacity` on it. The [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualopacity.aspx) says,

> The value of the opacity of the Visual is expressed as a value between 0 and 1. **A value of 0 indicates that the element is completely transparent**, whereas a value of 1 indicates that the element is completely opaque. A value of 0.5 indicates that the element is 50 percent opaque. Values that are less than 0 are treated as 0; values that are greater than 1 are treated as 1.

Hope that helps.